# asp.net 5, exclude .js files for typescript files

Tags: asp.net, typescript, visual-studio-2005

Is there a way to prevent the generated .js-files from being added to the solution when adding / saving a typescript file? I'm using Visual Studio 2015 CTP6 and ASP.NET 5.

-Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is but it will prevent typescript files from being compiled on save.

Add the following to your .kproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>False</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You can use grunt to produce js files from your ts since ts files will no longer be compiled on save.

Add grunt-ts to your package.json file

```
"grunt-ts": "^3.0.0"
```

Your gruntfile.js might look something like this:

```
ts: {
        dev: {
            src: ['app/src/ts/**/*.ts'],
            outDir: 'ts-bin',
            options: {
                fast: 'never',
                sourceRoot: 'js/app',
                verbose: true}
        }
    },
```

Documentation for grunt-ts is here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ts

One last tip: In VS2015, you can specify a grunt task that will trigger after builds using either the Task Runner Explorer in the GUI or by editing your project.json to include something like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "postrestore": [ "npm install" ],
    "prepare": [ "grunt bower:install" ],
    "postbuild": [ "grunt default" ]
}
```

Now your TS files will be compiled into JS on every build.